# PHP Insert JSON to MySql Multitable

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've this multidimensional array to insert into mysql database :

```
{
  customer_id: "25",
  total: 238000,
  firstname: "oci",
  product: [
             {
              product_id: "6",
              product_name: "Orange"
             },
             {
              product_id: "5",
              product_name: "Melon"
             }
         ]
}
```

This my code

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$customer_id= $_POST['customer_id'];
$total= $_POST['total'];
$firstname= $_POST['firstname'];

foreach ($_POST['product'] as $q_product => $v) {
    $product_id = $v['product_id'];
    $product_name= $v['product_name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_order
(order_id,customer_id,total,firstname) VALUES (NULL,'$customer_id','$total','$firstname')";
    
$queryy = "INSERT INTO tbl_order_product
    (order_id,product_id,product_name) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),$product_id,'$product_name')";
}
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$resultt = mysqli_query($link, $queryy);
```

I can't insert "queryy" to tbl_order_product, only tbl_order table
Please help me to insert 'product' array into tbl_order_product table too..

Comment: execute the queries inside the loop, otherwise only the last iteration will be executed. And use parameterized queries, yours are vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: *"I can't insert "queryy" to tbl_order_product, only tbl_order table Please help me to insert 'product' array into tbl_order_product table too.."* And please, describe your problem correctly. Any error message ? Any unexpected result ?

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: if($resultt){
  $status= array('status' => 'true');
 } else {
  $status= array('status' => 'false');
 }
 echo json_encode($status);

But Result always show False Status.. no error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your query execution should be inside loop otherwise only last product details will be populated in both tables.
2. Don't use LAST_INSERT_ID() in php, instead use php function for the same.
3. Don't pass order_id as `null` and make sure it is auto incremental.
4. Use prepared statement to prevent sql injection.

Simple update to your question to get it working(doesn't include sql injection prevention)

```
foreach ($_POST['product'] as $q_product => $v) {
    $product_id    = $v['product_id'];
    $product_name  = $v['product_name'];

    $query   =  "INSERT INTO tbl_order (customer_id,total,firstname) 
                VALUES ('$customer_id','$total','$firstname')";
    
    $result  =   mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $last_id =   mysqli_insert_id($link);

    $queryy  =  "INSERT INTO tbl_order_product (order_id,product_id,product_name) 
                 VALUES ($last_id ,$product_id,'$product_name')";

    $resultt =   mysqli_query($link, $queryy);   
}
```

To use prepared statement to prevent sql injection, please have a look at these.

1. [PHP MySQL Prepared Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)
2. [INSERT query using PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I try it but nor working...

Comment: Can you try now? I removed `order_id` from first query( if it is primary key then don't pass anything and make sure it is auto incremental. If any error is there please do share that with us.